# PHP: Display a form only if database value equals X

Tags: php

I have added a form into an admin panel with a yes (1) and no (0) option.

I have changed the Db so that on submit, the value gets added to the Db with the value "seller" 1 or 0, which works fine.

I have a form on my site.  I only want it to display to a logged in person if they have a value in the Db of "1" for seller.  If they have a value of 0 I want to print a message.

I am guessing I need to query the database, then construct a function and apply it in the page where the form code is to display it if the condition of "1" is met?

I have tried searching but cannot grasp how I can construct it.

Comment: [Use a `WHERE` clause](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)

Comment: Or an IF()...ELSE in php. The clue is in your question "if the condition of "1" is met"

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
// insert your DB Data
$user = "";
$pass = "";
$host = "";
$dbdb = "";

$connect = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $dbdb);
if(!$connect)
{
    trigger_error('Error connection to database: '.mysqli_connect_error());
}

mysqli_set_charset($connect, 'utf8'); 

$query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT `seller` FROM `nameTable` WHERE `user` = 'userName'");
$record = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

if($record['seller'] == 1){
    echo "Seller is 1";
}else{
    echo "Seller is 0";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using **if else condition** for my solution here:

```
 <?php

    $userLoggedIn = $_SESSION['userName'];//session created while login is stored in variable

    //Search table `tbl` for field `SELLER` where field `user` matches with loggedin user

    $searchSeller = mysql_query("SELECT `SELLER` from `tbl` WHERE `user`='$userLoggedIn'");
    $searchSellerArray = mysql_fetch_array($searchSeller);

    //Setting variable to be used in css depending on value in table

    if($searchSellerArray['seller']==1){

    $displayForm="block";//displays form
    $displayMessage="none";//hides message

    }
    elseif ($searchSellerArray['seller']==0){

    $displayForm="none";//hides form
    $displayMessage="block";//displays message

    }
    ?>

    <form style="display:<?php echo $displayForm;?>;">
    //Form content goes here...
    </form>
    <p style="display:<?php echo $displayMessage;?>;">
    //Message content goes here
    </p>
```

Comment: Even better to use mySQLi.

Comment: `from 'tbl'` that is being translated as a string literal

Comment: I tried The above but just got PHP connection errors.  I'm lost.  Basically this is the script: